# Can I specify datetime format when using Django JSON serializer to serialize DatetimeField

Tags: python, json, django, datetime, serialization

It seems that it always serializes datetime field to iso format.
My Django version is 1.6.5. My expected format is something like "2014-08-08 16:00:00". However, the output is always like "2014-08-08T16:00:00", no matter how I change the datetime format in settings. It seems that that setting cannot control the format for serialization.
Do I have any way to change the format?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
```

you have to use:

```
datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(' ')
```

Details here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

#### EDIT

When you serialize the querystring using `DjangoJSONEncoder`, it parses `datetime` in `isoformat()`, so you need to override it.

```
import datetime
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
import decimal
from django.utils.timezone import is_aware

class DjangoOverRideJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    """
    JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to encode date/time and decimal types.
    """
    def default(self, o):
        # See "Date Time String Format" in the ECMA-262 specification.
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            r = o.isoformat(' ')
            if o.microsecond:
                r = r[:23] + r[26:]
            if r.endswith('+00:00'):
                r = r[:-6] + 'Z'
            return r
        elif isinstance(o, datetime.date):
            return o.isoformat(' ')
        elif isinstance(o, datetime.time):
            if is_aware(o):
                raise ValueError("JSON can't represent timezone-aware times.")
            r = o.isoformat(' ')
            if o.microsecond:
                r = r[:12]
            return r
        elif isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        else:
            return super(DjangoOverRideJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Now you need to use like this:

```
>>data= json.dumps(list(Model.objects.all()), cls=DjangoOverRideJSONEncoder)
>>print data
 '[{"last_updated": "2014-07-09 15:26:06",  "date_created": "2014-07-09 15:26:06","id": 11}, {"last_updated": "2014-08-25 10:48:31.946", "date_created": "2014-08-25 10:47:59.656", "id": 49093}]'
```